# Eigenvalues of A(adj A). Are they necessarily real?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I do not understand how if det(A) comes out to be a complex number then the eigenvalues will still be real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) from [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of a matrix. In this context, it refers to the conjugate transpose.

Guide:

A possible way to solve the problem is to consider the SVD of $A$, compute $A^*$ and then compute $AA^*$ and $A^*A$.